# When does a flying creature knocked prone fall and how far?

Tags: dnd-5e, combat, movement, falling, prone

I understand according to the rules for flying that

> If a flying creature is knocked prone, has its speed reduced to 0, or is otherwise deprived of the ability to move, the creature falls, unless it has the ability to hover or it is being held aloft by magic, such as the fly spell.

However, my question is when the flying creature is given the prone status *when does it begin to fall*, and *how far does it fall*?

an example is as follows:

A **3rd level Battlemaster Fighter** confirms a hit on a **Harpy** flying 30ft above the ground. The Battlemaster then expends a superiority die to use their **trip attack**, the harpy then fails its **strength save** and is knocked **prone**.

Comment: I've marked your question as a dupe because I think it has been asked before. This isn't a bad thing as this question might help others find that one. If that question doesn't answer it for you, please clarify for us how and why and we'll see what needs to be done to help you.

Comment: Ahh thank you I somehow missed that one the question I kept getting as a suggestion as similar was https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/51059/what-happens-when-a-flying-creature-is-knocked-prone